# Fancybox 2 Height not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to get two different heights from my fancybox depending on which link the client clicks on, but for some reason the height just keeps going to 100%. It's not going to the height I'm wanting

This is my code

```
$('.fancyboxhd').fancybox({
  width: 1287,
  height: 720
});
$('.fancyboxsd').fancybox({
  width: 640,
  height: 360,
});
```

It's an iFrame content

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**(*see edit below for an improved answer*)**

For iframe content, your html should look like

```
<a class="fancyboxhd fancybox.iframe" href="hdfile.html">hd</a>
<a class="fancyboxsd fancybox.iframe" href="sdfile.html">sd</a>
```

then add these two options to your scripts

```
fitToView   : false,
autoSize    : false
```

so your scripts should look like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.fancyboxhd').fancybox({
   width : 1287,
   height : 720,
   fitToView : false,
   autoSize : false
 });
 $('.fancyboxsd').fancybox({
   width: 640,
   height: 360,
   fitToView : false,
   autoSize : false
 });
});
```

**### EDIT ###** : (Sep 05, 2013)

The code can be improved and simplified using (HTML5) `data-*` attributes in the anchors and the same `class` for both options like :

HTML

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" data-width="1287" data-height="720" href="hdfile.html">HD</a>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" data-width="640"  data-height="360" href="sdfile.html">SD</a>
```

JS

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    fitToView: false,
    autoSize: false,
    afterLoad: function () {
        this.width = $(this.element).data("width");
        this.height = $(this.element).data("height");
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hvGRv/)**

**NOTE**: At the time of this edit, demo used fancybox v2.1.5.

Comment: Thanks it worked. My issue was that I was specifying `fitToView` and `autoSize` before the fixed `width` and `height`.

Comment: FitToView: false was the key here for the issue I was having. Thanks!

Comment: i was also having same problem, it worked for me as well. thanks

Answer (score 0):

for v2.1.5 you can use this by using the id of html element.

```
<a id="item1" class="fancybox" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/YtwCt/show/">Open 500x200</a>

<br />

<a id="item2" class="fancybox" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/YtwCt/show/">Open 200x500</a>

<div id="test" style="display:none">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar, nulla eu interdum posuere, nisi mauris cursus nisi, nec faucibus nibh urna nec turpis.


$(".fancybox-wrap").draggable();
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        autoSize : false,
        beforeLoad : function() {         
            if ($(this.element).attr('id') == 'item1') {
                this.width  = 500;
                this.height = 200;
            }
        else {
                this.width  = 200;
                this.height = 500;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

set **autoScale : false,**

```
$('.fancyboxhd').fancybox({
  width: 1287,
  height: 720,
  autoScale : false,
});
```