# Open fancy box with iframe specifying the height as a %

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to open a fancybox modal with the content type being an iframe and I want to specify the height as a %.

If I use

```
    $(".FullWindow").fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    href: 'http://www.google.com',
    autoSize: false,
    width: "95%",
    height: "95%"
});
```

then this opens the modal to the correct size (but does not load the url - I only added the href property as a test) but when I use

```
    $(".FullWindow").fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    autoSize: false,
    width: "95%",
    height: "95%"
});
```

the page opens but not at 95% of the window height.

I guess I am missing something simple

**PROBLEM SOLVED
Updated to the latest version of fancybox and the latest version of JQuery and it now works fine.
Thanks to those who offered help.**

Comment: Try setting 'autoScale': false

Comment: @markpsmith : `autoScale` is not a valid option for the new version of fancybox (the one the OP seems to be using)

Comment: Your code works fine **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbBYh/)** ... otherwise check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10303090/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox 2 Height not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295746/fancybox-2-height-not-working)

Comment: BTW, you cannot open google in an iframe ... check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9372804/1055987 for more

Comment: Try adding `fitToView: false`