# fancybox2 100% width? and scrollable with browsers scrollbar // mobile ready

Tags: jquery, mobile, fancybox, lightbox

fancybox should be 100% width and height, and scrollable with the scrollbars from the browser.
And to work for mobile devices.

my project: http://f-designs.de/test_onesite/#portfolio (first picture opens in fancybox)

for example what i want: http://hochburg.net/de/#/meisterwerk/26

what i have tried:

```
// FANCYBOX
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    margin: 0,
    autoSize: false,
    width: "100%",
    height:"100%",

        helpers : {
          overlay : {
            locked: true    
          } 
        }
 });
```

the div open in the fancybox with 100% width and height... but have own scrollbars but i want to scroll with the browsers scrollbar only.

and on mobile devices overlay locked have no effect.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far to achieve what you are wanting? Us being able to see the code can help you get an answer faster.

Comment: Have you tried fitToView: false,
    autoSize: false,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295746/fancybox-2-height-not-working

Comment: @Brett if i add fitToView: false and autoSize: false ... dont to nothing

Comment: Try to delete the height 100% you just limit it to the height of the screen the problem is the fancybox-inner height, if you remove it in devtools (F12) than it is full height. try to google it from their

Comment: the problem is that i want to scroll with the browsers scrollbar, not with the second from fancybox, check the example what i want:

http://hochburg.net/de/#/meisterwerk/26